# Paging million recored

Tags: search-engine

I am sorry if my question is stupid.

When I search on google and it returns the number of result usually about over one hundred million results. How many clicks I have to do when I wanna go to the last result with google's paging bar like this : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 >

Answer (score 0):

Google only returns between 300 and 1,000 results, no matter how many documents they have in their index matching a query. So you will never get to the last page. Sorry.

Comment: So from 1001 to the rest of the results are garbages. Thanks